# Synced a Git branch in Visual Studio; where did it go?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I just synched a Git repository that I am developing in Visual Studio. The sync ran without error and indicates that there are no outgoing commits. Problem is, I have no idea what it synched with. The code didn't go to my [Github profile](https://github.com/jbnv) nor my [Visual Studio Online profile](https://jbnv.visualstudio.com/). It's not in [CodePlex](https://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/bienvenunet) either. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call "git remote show" from the command line you should see the remotes. If you do "git push" it will only push to the default remote even if you have multiple.

You should change the origin, the default, to be VSO.

Comment: More specifically, "git remote show origin." Revealed that Git was pushing my site to Azure. Which is correct, as I had created the project in Azure.